# How to register C++ class constructor to Lua userdata and use it by default

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

Using the Lua C API, I registered a simple `Object` class to Lua, like this:

```
// My C++ Object class
class Object {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Object(double x) : x(x){}
};

// Create and return instance of Object class to Lua
int object_new(lua_State* L)
{
    double x = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    *reinterpret_cast<Object**>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Object*))) = new Object(x);
    luaL_setmetatable(L, "Object");
    return 1;
}

// Functions to register to Lua
const luaL_Reg functions[] =
{
    {"new", object_new},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

// Register the Object class to Lua
luaL_newmetatable(L, "Object");
luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
```

In my Lua script, the following works just fine:

```
// Works!
my_object = Object.new(42)
```

But, I would like to be able to do this (i.e. omit the `.new` part):

```
// Fail :(
my_object = Object(42)
```

But when I execute the Lua script, I get this error:

```
...attempt to call a table value (global 'Object').
```

Is there a way to register a C++ class in a way that the constructor gets called if we don't provide a function name? What did I miss to make this work? That would be particularly useful for temporary objects.

Thanks!

Comment: C neither has classes nor constructors.

Comment: Sure, just add a `__call` metamethod to your `Object` metatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the return of [luaL_newmetatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_newmetatable) to register your metamethods just once.

You can replace `luaL_setmetatable` by `luaL_newmetatable`, so your code is compatible to Lua 5.1, you can embed the metatable registration into the *constructor* and it works the same (except the additional `lua_setmetatable`).

For a constructor, just register a function. The metatable should manage an instance, not his creation.

Don't forget to add a deconstructor (**__gc**) to free your allocated C++ class instance.

At the end you have just to register function `Object` which creates the metatable at his first call.

```
#define LUA_META_OBJECT "Object"

class Object {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Object(double x) : x(x){}
};

static int object_free(lua_State* L)
{
    delete *static_cast<Object**>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_META_OBJECT));
    return 0;
}

static int object_new(lua_State* L)
{
    const lua_Number x = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    *static_cast<Object**>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Object*))) = new Object(x);
    if(luaL_newmetatable(L, LUA_META_OBJECT)){
        static const luaL_Reg functions[] =
        {
            {"__gc", object_free},
            {nullptr, nullptr}
        };
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    }
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;
}

...
    lua_register(L, "Object", object_new);
...
```

Comment: @Rochet2 `In both cases pushes onto the stack the final value associated with tname in the registry.` The metatable is **always** pushed! Just the metatable definition happens once because further calls of `luaL_newmetatable` return 0.

Comment: I was not talking about pushing the metatable. I was talking about the creation. The metatable is *never* created because a key already exists with the name "Object", which is the function you define at the bottom.

Comment: @Rochet2 You ever tested my code or read the manual properly? There's a difference between the [global environment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2) and the [registry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.5)! **lua_register** sets the function to the environment table for use in Lua, **luaL_newmetatable** sets the metatable to the registry table for use in C. There's no replacement.

Comment: Ah yes, that is the key difference. Thanks!

Comment: @Rochet2 does that make your answer different based on what Youka said?

Comment: @Deathicon Our answers use different methods but achieve the same goal. In my code the metatable `Object` is exposed in lua and another metatable is used to get what you wanted. In Youka's answer the metatable used for userdata is not accessible from lua (correct me if wrong) and a function called `Object` is made to get what you wanted. Youka's answer might be more efficient and "safer" as the function is called directly and it doesnt expose the metatable for scripts to mess with.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like Youka's answer, but I wanted to implement this differently. Most of the code here is borrowed from Youka's answer.

Youka also made an important note that you *need* to make a `__gc` metamethod as well so you wont have a memory leak when your Object instances go out of scope

In the code below I made a separate function that pushes the metatable to the stack and creates it if it didnt exist yet. The metatable itself has a metatable that has `__call` metamethod that calls the object creation. This behavior should allow you to use `o = Object(42)` to make new objects. I also included the code to still have the old functionality using `o = Object.new(42)`.
At the bottom of the code the metatable is pushed once to create the metatable initially.

```
#define LUA_META_OBJECT "Object"

class Object {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Object(double x) : x(x){}
};

// declaration so we can use this in object_new function
int push_object_metatable(lua_State* L);

static int object_free(lua_State* L)
{
    delete *static_cast<Object**>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_META_OBJECT));
    return 0;
}

static int object_new(lua_State* L)
{
    const lua_Number x = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    *static_cast<Object**>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Object*))) = new Object(x);
    push_object_metatable(L);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;
}

static int call_object_new(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_remove(L, 1);
    object_new(L);
    return 1;
}

// Pushes the metatable for Object and creates if it doesnt exist yet
int push_object_metatable(lua_State* L)
{
    if(luaL_newmetatable(L, LUA_META_OBJECT)){
        static const luaL_Reg functions[] =
        {
            {"new", object_new},
            {"__gc", object_free},
            {nullptr, nullptr}
        };
        luaL_setfuncs(L, functions, 0);
        lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

        // Set a metatable for the metatable :D
        // This allows using Object(42) to make new objects
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_pushcfunction(L, call_object_new);
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "__call");
        lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    }
    return 1;
}

...
    // Register Object metatable for lua (Create and push it)
    push_object_metatable(L);
    lua_setglobal(L, LUA_META_OBJECT);
...
```

Comment: I like your solution but in the end I preferred Youka's answer to highlight difference between how I create _userdata_ objects versus _lightuserdata_ objects. Thanks!